# '[WinError 6] The handle is invalid' When building any python file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, handle, windows-error-reporting

Whenever I try to Build (ctrl + b) any python file in Sublime Text 3, I get this error: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid. It was working fine before and all of a sudden started giving me this error.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 is still in beta. Beta software questions are off-topic here on Superuser. I'd recommend asking via Sublime Text's own support channels.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore Minor hint: Questions about beta software are absolutely on topic here – after all, many programs never get out of beta for years. Questions about *bugs* in those are off topic.

Comment: @slhck My fault for not clarifying that.